# Vim short binding for <C-w>| doesn't work

Tags: vim

Trying to map horizontal maximize to something two keystrokes less, but none of these works:

```
nnoremap <leader>\ <c-w>| " Maximize horizontally

nnoremap <c-\\> <c-w>|  " Maximize horizontally
```

At the same time these two work fine:

```
nnoremap <leader>- <c-w>_ " Maximize vertically
nnoremap <leader>= <c-w>= " Restore default size
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bar character `|` is a command separator in Vim script. To use it in a mapping, use `<Bar>`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>\ <C-W><Bar>
```

The relevant documentation is at [`:h map_bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map_bar).