# bash substitutions in vimscript

Tags: bash, vim, substitution

How can I use bash substitutions in mapped commands in `vimscript`?

Vim does work well with `&&` operator but it does not like bash `$(command)` operator and backticks operator.

In my `.vimrc` I have such a simplified line:

```
nnoremap SOME_KEY :!java $(echo % | sed 's/\.java//') <CR>
```

I would expect running `java Test` command on pressing `SOME_KEY` if my current file is `Test.java`.

Instead it results in the following error `E492: Not an editor command:  sed 's/\.java//')`

What is the correct way to use bash substitutions in commands executed on pressing a key in vim? Is there a better way to do what I try to accomplish?

Comment: Same problem at [Vim short binding for <C-w>| doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14717388).

Comment: For sure. I tried to search but... I couldn't succeed, this type of questions is a bit hard-searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `|` with `<bar>`.

If you insert `|` into a mapping vim interprets the characters after `|` as a new command.

Hence, in your case vim rightly complains about `sed 's/\.java//'` isn't  an editor command.

Another way to implement your mapping would be

```
nnoremap SOME_KEY :call system("java $(echo ". expand('%') ." | sed 's/\.java//')")<CR>
```

Comment: The mapping is also probably missing the trailing `<CR>`. See all those special codes at `:help key-notation`.

Comment: I had <CR> in the end, I removed it while simplifying the example. I returned it back.

Answer (score 2):

Vim is interpreting the `|` as a command separator in vim not as a pipe in bash.

To fix this you can either escape the `|` with `\|` or use `<bar>`

However this is really no reason to be executing this command in bash. This is the same as the following in viml.

```
nnoremap SOME_KEY :!java shellescape(expand('%:r'))<CR>
```

`%:r` is the current file name without extension.

This one also has the added benefit of escaping the filename just in case the name has spaces or some other weird characters.

Relevant help pages `:h filename-modifiers`, `:h :bar`, `:h shellescape()`, `:h expand()`

Comment: Although I have solved the problem with @user1146332 solution, +1 for the much shorter one

Comment: In the case you invoked `sed` merely to remove the suffix of the file being edited `:nnoremap SOME_KEY :exe "!java '%:p:h'"<CR>` is even shorter.

Comment: @user1146332 you do not want `%:p:h`. java does not want the full path to the file. It wants a relative one. (The full path introduces packages that don't exist.). Also `%:p:h` might have problems in the shell if there are spaces in it.

Comment: Thank your for the hint. I have no idea about java. If you put `%:p:h`  into single quotes like i did problems are rare.

Comment: @user1146332 missed the fact it was in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nnoremap SOME_KEY :exec '!java ' . expand("%:r")<CR>
```

Vim already has a method to strip the extension `expand("%:r")`.  Using `exec` is a good way to do something based on concatenating strings.

Comment: You can don't need `expand()` here. `:exe "!java '%:p:h'"<CR>` suffices for the right hand side of your mapping like i mentioned in a comment above.