# Vim key mapping to execute a python script

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map a command in Vim for the first time.
I want it to execute the current python script, so I put the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <silent><F5> :wall | !clear && echo "% is running..." && python %<CR>
```

When I start Vim I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `clear && echo "/home/ekirstein/.vimrc is running..." && python /home/ekirstein/CR>'
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is the exact same problem as in the second most recent [vim] question, [bash substitutions in vimscript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17883131). Also [Vim short binding for <C-w>| doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14717388). Should probably start a collection of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks glts. I forgot to escape the pipe...

```
noremap <silent><F5> :wall \| !clear && echo "% is running..." && python %<CR>
```

Comment: Or use `<Bar>` (this is mostly used); see `:help key-notation`.